# How do I convert XML to JSON AWS API Gateway?

Tags: json, xml, amazon-web-services, soap, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to use Amazon's AWS API gateway to front legacy SOAP services with REST.  I am able to take a resource request and basically hard code SOAP request in a Body Mapping Template.  The SOAP service is called and the XML SOAP response is returned. So far so good.

In the Integration Response, I need to take this SOAP envelope (Basically just XML) and map that back to the JSON model.  I don't see how this can be done, but I must be missing something. The following code will get the raw response, but I don't see any way to access the elements:

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
 $input.body
}
```

Imagine my response looks like this:

```html
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:getProdResponse xmlns:ns1="urn:productlist">
         <code xsi:type="xsd:string">100</return>
         <message xsi:type="xsd:string">this is a book</return>
      </ns1:getProdResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Then in a Body Mapping Template, I want to do something like this:

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
    "response-code" : "$input.Envelope.Body.getProdResponse.code",
    "response-message" : "$input.Envelope.Body.getProdResponse.message"
}
```

I know I can probably write a Lambda function to call the SOAP service, but that just doesn't seem reasonable.  Am I out of luck?

Comment: @paulsm4 the question is specifically about creating an AWS API Gateway mapping template. The transformation would occur within the API Gateway service. This isn't a JavaScript question, and the transformation isn't happening in a browser.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

API Gateway does not currently support direct transformation of XML response bodies.  This is a commonly requested feature and is on our backlog, so it will likely get implemented eventually.  In the meantime, the only option is to us a Lambda function to call your SOAP back end, parse the response, and return JSON to API Gateway.

Comment: Thanks for confirming Mike!

Comment: @MikeD What's the current status of JSON to XML conversion in AWS API Gateway?

Comment: It's still on the backlog, but has not been prioritized for implementation yet.

Comment: @MikeDatAWS What's the current status of this ask ? Any idea when this functionality would be added ?

Comment: why is there not a wrapper or some VTL syntax to convert a XML response to a JSON equivalent still in 2021? seems like wrapping a legacy soap w/s would be a great use case for API gateway and all the competitors seem to offer it