# How to append a prefix to a querystring parameter in AWS API Gateway?

Tags: aws-api-gateway

When setting up `URL Query String Parameters` in the `Integration Request` part of an API method, it looks like I have [the following options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-method-settings-execution-console.html)

- reference a value from `method.request.{path|querystring|header}.{var-name}`
- use a fixed single-quoted string

Even though API Gateway [allows complex mappings on the body via VTL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/request-response-data-mappings.html#transforming-request-response-body), it looks like [querystring, header, and path variables do not have this option](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/request-response-data-mappings.html#mapping-response-parameters).

The specific use case I have is I want to populate the `prefix` query parameter for [a call to S3's REST API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/v2-RESTBucketGET.html) with something like: `'read'+method.request.path.folder`, so all `GET` requests start under a prefix (without the user having to specify that prefix).

Is there a way for me to achieve this goal using API Gateway?

Comment: Oh wow it looks like api gateway doesn't support XML->JSON transformations either, even though all the responses from AWS APIs are XML: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40325005/how-do-i-convert-xml-to-json-aws-api-gateway

Comment: I suspect your use case calls for a Lambda function.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm thinking at this point too @Michael-sqlbot.